# Retrieve Movie Pricing like in IMDB

Tags: ios

I need to know, how we can get pricing list for any valid particular movie. Like in iTunes there are many movies app, which gives pricing for all website for live streaming. How to retrieve that list of pricing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to get **iTunes Store Movie Metadata**, which include pricing. You can use **iTunes Store Search API**, which also returns iTunes pricing.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=ventura&media=movie
```

This API call will return JSON response with the following data:

```
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"feature-movie", "trackId":271495352, "artistName":"Steve Oedekerk", "trackName":"Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls", "trackCensoredName":"Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/ace-ventura-when-nature-calls/id271495352?uo=4", "previewUrl":"http://a1567.v.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/035/Video/39/3b/c3/mzm.idnfqvpl..720w.h264lc.D2.p.m4v", "artworkUrl30":"http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Video/61/32/8b/mzl.vpqgqzrg.30x30-50.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Video/61/32/8b/mzl.vpqgqzrg.60x60-50.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Video/61/32/8b/mzl.vpqgqzrg.100x100-75.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":9.99, "trackRentalPrice":2.99000, "collectionHdPrice":14.99000, "trackHdPrice":14.99000, "trackHdRentalPrice":3.99000, "releaseDate":"2013-10-02T07:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackTimeMillis":5641183, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Comedy", "contentAdvisoryRating":"PG-13", 
"longDescription":"Africa's the place and Ace is on the case, setting out to rescue an animal he loathes: a bat! Jim Carrey (Batman Forever) returns as Ace, the alligator-wrasslin', elephant-calling, monkey-shining, loogie-launching, burning coals-crossing, disguise-mastering pet detective. If you're ready to laugh like a pack of hyenas, if you want more fun than an industrial-sized barrel of monkeys, you know what to do. Heed the call.", "radioStationUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/station/idra.271495352"}
```

Be careful of the following parameters:

- collectionPrice
- trackPrice
- trackRentalPrice
- collectionHdPrice
- trackHdPrice
- trackHdRentalPrice

*If you are looking for other website streaming prices, I would try to look for the specific API's on service side that would provide you with this information.*

The more mature services usually provide REST API's to access it's information. What you are looking to do is basically - creating an **abstract pricing layer** on top of all available API's. While this answer would be too long going into detail on each and every service, I can give you some information for the sites you mentioned:

- Hulu API: https://github.com/adammagana/hulu-php-library
- Vudu API: https://github.com/jfx41/vudu
- Rotten Tomatoes (Flixster) API: http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/
- Amazon API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

While those links will not solve your problem out of the box, you should be able to get enough information from them to actually understand what can you do.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer, however I want to get information from all, like Hulu, Vudu, Amazon, Flixster etc. Like I click on movie and it will show me list of options availability with pricing.

Comment: Updated with information I could find for sites you mentioned.